# How to call php file from js in word press?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

How to call a php file using jquery in wordpress?

My folder structure is like this:

```
- api
  - test.php
- js
  - script.js
- pages
```

I have following lines inside

### test.php

```
$array = array(
    "name" => "Auto",
    "strabe" => "28",
);

echo json_encode($array);
```

### script.js

```
$(function () {
    $("#btn-search").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: './api/test.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response)
            {
                let result = JSON.parse(response);
                console.log(result);
            },
            failure: function(response)
            {
                alert("Error found");
            }
        });



    });

})
```

But I am getting page not found error.

Comment: first, create a variable like this in **.php** file
`var site_url = '<?=get_site_url?>'; //use this variable to get site url
var directory_url = '<?=get_template_directory_uri(); ?>'; //use this variable to get directory url`

Answer (score 0):

use ***get_template_directory_uri()*** before url of file

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/